# PDF document error using Zend_Pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7, zend-pdf

In magento1.7, I have tried something like below in my custom controller.

```
public function getPDF()
{
$imagePath=C:\Users\.........;
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath);
$page->drawImage($image, 40,764,240, 820);
.
.
.
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
$pdf->save("mydoc.pdf");
}
```

There's no error in it. It generates PDF with image but the PDF document is saved in magento folder instead in My downloads folder. After doing some research, I found some following chunk of lines and added them after $pdf->pages[] = $page;.

```
  $pdfString = $pdf->render();
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
  header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
  echo $pdfString;
```

Now it generates PDF in My Downloads folder. When I try to open it. It throws error saying : Adobe reader couldn't open myfile.pdf because it's not either a supported file type or because the file has been damaged............ Do this happens,when we try to open PDF document generated on localhost or there's some other reason. Please let me know, why this error occurs and also provide me a solution to resolve it.

Comment: Can you look at the content of the PDF file in a text editor and see anything like PHP errors or warnings displayed in the pdf file?  How big is the file that it saves?

Comment: Also, you are saving the file with a different file name (mydoc.pdf vs myfile.pdf).

Comment: @drew010: I tried to open PDF document in text editor, it contains mixture html of current phtml file (i.e file in which the function getPDF() is called) and alpha-numeric characters. I think, error occurs due to the presence of html content in it.The size of the file is more than 6500k.Can you help me in resolving this...

Comment: @JamesG: No, it doesn't matter whether we are saving file with the different file name. If I save the file with "myfile.pdf" name, the same error still occurs.

Comment: @Nida For starters add these lines before you output the PDF, if it works I'll add it as an answer.  `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true); $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();`  This is standard ZF code to prevent the layout and action views from being rendered, hopefully those same helper are available in Magento.

Comment: @drew010: I have tried  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true); $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();          It throws error message: Call to a member function setNoRender() on a non-object. How to get these helper methods in magento?

Comment: @Nida Try these lines instead: `$vr = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $vr->setNoRender(true);

        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $layout->disableLayout();`

Comment: Now these two lines $vr = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer'); $vr->setNoRender(true) works but these two lines $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance(); $layout->disableLayout(); doesn't works. And now the error message is "Call to a member function disableLayout() on a non-object".Also can you please specify at which place should I call these lines of code

Comment: What's wrong with just renaming/moving the file to where you want it with normal php then header redirecting to it?

Comment: also 'My Documents' is no good. You need 'my_documents' to give it a fair chance.

Comment: Could you post actual code? If those three first line are exactly as you have in your code there's an obvious issue where you are using $page as an object before it's defined.. Hard to guess without a bit more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is probably due to calling both save() and render() together.

save() actually calls render(), the issue could be due to trying to render the PDF twice.

This is also a waste of resources, if you need to save the file it's probably best to just save the file first, and then serve this file directly to the user.

You can do this in plain old PHP (using passthru or readfile), although there's ways to do this inside Zendframework which are better you can look into :)

```
// .. create PDF here.. 
$pdf->save("mydoc.pdf");

$file = 'mydoc.pdf';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

if your code is inside a Magento Controller:

```
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
        ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType, true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file))
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"')
        ->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));

    $this->getResponse()->clearBody();
    $this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();

    $ioAdapter = new Varien_Io_File();
    if (!$ioAdapter->fileExists($file)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('File not found'));
    }
    $ioAdapter->open(array('path' => $ioAdapter->dirname($file)));
    $ioAdapter->streamOpen($file, 'r');
    while ($buffer = $ioAdapter->streamRead()) {
        print $buffer;
    }
    $ioAdapter->streamClose();
    exit(0);
```

Comment: Why use Varien_Io_File and not something like: `if(file_exists($file)) { $this->getResponse()->setBody(file_get_contents($file));}` ?

Comment: If the file is big you'll get into trouble as you're reading the full thing and storing it as a string inside the response..